# Place multi v-model in my double value select in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-model

I have this select class which get me the id ($key) in options and amount($value) in th output. 
I placed v-model="update.bank" correctly so i have my amount in my vue. But i need also to save the id with v-model="update.id" and this is not working..

My code :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <label for="title">Select Funding:</label>
            <select data-validation="number"  class="form-control" style="width:200px" v-model="update.bank">

                      @foreach ($users as $keys => $values)
                <option value="{{ $keys }}" v-model="update.codeentry">  {{ $values }}</option> 
                       @endforeach
             </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: please my bro provide more code snippet

Comment: `update.bank` should already contain the `value` of the selected option.

Comment: Yes ! but i need the $key value into my update.id

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim what do you need exactly ?  thanks in advance

Comment: `$key` value is already in `update.bank` why not use that? if you really want it that way, you can use `computed` property.

Comment: i need to see your data object

Comment: @Wreigh update.bank got the $value value

Comment: read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select-Options